# rails won"t execute a perl script in the same folder as the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple method

```
  def execperl
  system("perl myscript.pl")
  redirect_to :controller => :mycontroller, :action => :index
  end
```

Where I put this mycontroller (that contains index and execperl) in the same folder as the myscript.pl.

However, when I execute the method, it just go back to index, and when I see the console, no sign that myscript.pl is executed. 
If I execute myscript.pl manually using perl myscript.pl, it works just fine

How can I execute myscript.pl in the same location as the mycontroller file?

Thank you for any answer.

|edit
I read that in the log, it is written "can't open perl script myscript.pl" No such file or directory.

Do I have to specify the location of the script in system("perl myscript.pl")? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
system("/usr/bin/perl #{Rails.root}/app/controllers/myscript.pl")
```

Comment: I wrote system("perl C:\user\me\myscript.pl") does not work , thus showing error of Can"t open perlscript "C:\"No such file or directory

Comment: @rahardi: He's suggesting that you try specifying the full path to `perl.exe`, the error looks like `system()` can't find `perl.exe`. And careful with your backslashes, double them (`C:\\blah\\....`) or just use forward slashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory is not the directory your script is in.  The path to your script is something like:

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "myscript.pl")
```